# Почему при копировании из TextBox в .txt появляются лишние переходы на новую строку?

Tags: c#, winforms

Почему при копировании из `TextBox` например в `.txt` ручками появляются лишние переходы на новую строку ?

```
textBox1.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
```

При вставке в сам TextBox нет никаких лишних строк, каждый текст с новой строки.

Но при копировании куда либо в другое место, появляются пустые строки между строк.

Так в TextBox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если ручками `выделить всё` -> `копировать` -> `вставить` в .txt то так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update:**

Каким то боком, если получить `textBox1.Text`, то оказывается что между строку такое `\r\r\n`

**Update2:**

Моя ошибка, в переменной `text` уже есть в конце `\r`, а я добавляю `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: это что? Winforms? что значит "при копировании"? куда именно? какой редактор?

Comment: Уверены что это пустые строки а не большой разрыв между абзацами?

Comment: Посмотрите на файл в Фаре в режиме хекс - какими символами заканчиваются строки? Может быть переводы строк нормальные, просто ваш редактор делает отдельные разрывы для #13 и отдельные для #10.

Comment: Так может text уже имеет разрыв строки в конце? Хотя, было бы в текстбоксе видно

Comment: @aepot да. это `WinForms`. Добавляется внутри `for` например как я указал кол указал код, а из textBox, я ручками `выделить всё` -> `копировать` -> `вставить` в .txt или Google Sheets. И вставляется текст с дополнительными пустыми строками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего сама строка содержит лишнее, думаю можно вот так решить

```
textBox1.AppendText(text.Trim() + Environment.NewLine);
```